# how can i align switch in navigation drawer menu?

Tags: android, xml

[Sample Navigation Drawer Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiQdt.png)

This is my navigation drawer layout

I cannot align this switch

[Sample Navigation Drawer Achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMnzQ.png)

like this

this is my xml code

toggle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">
<com.rey.material.widget.Switch
    style="@style/Material.Widget.Switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:checked="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

drawer.xml

```
<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
            android:title="menual" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/it_sw"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:title="ON/OFF"
            android:visible="true"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/toggle"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

what's wrong?

Comment: try android:gravity="center|center" @ your switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using this code, working fine. I hope you will get fix for what you want to do.

**menu_drawer.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mi_drawer_item_live_traffic"
    android:icon="@drawable/side_livetraffic"
    android:title="@string/drawer_item_live_traffic"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_switch"
    />
```

**layout_switch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/drawer_switch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to align switch to right of the parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.rey.material.widget.Switch
    style="@style/Material.Widget.Switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="Right"
    android:checked="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```